# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [2,2]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having `You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [2,2]`error.I have already fed the placeholder`aa`

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

aa = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(2, 2))
bb = tf.Variable(aa)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  print(sess.run(bb,feed_dict={aa:np.random.rand(2,2)}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `sess.run(init)`; you need a value for `aa` in order to initialize `bb`. `aa` is not needed to retrieve `bb` later, though, since it already has been assigned a value.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

aa = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(2, 2))
bb = tf.Variable(aa)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init, feed_dict={aa: np.random.rand(2, 2)})
  print(sess.run(bb))
```